# Video quality of http stream in VideoView (Adaptive streaming)

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, drm

I am working on video streaming application. I have to stream *.wvm which is adaptive-stream and it is DRM protected. Since the seek ability and buffering is required, I have custom VideoView.

PROBLEM:

1) In almost every android devices the video stream has bad quality of video. On other platforms (SmartTV, iOS) it seems like the same video has HD quality. Why it has so bad quality? How can I affect the video stream quality?

2) But sometimes the video loads in HD quality, but if so, the seeking is not working:

```
08-16 17:02:58.255: E/MediaPlayer(18024): error (1, -110)
```

- I was looking for descriptions of MediaPlayer error codes but I could not find anything (There was some *.h file on GitHub with some error codes but this was not complete).
- I have a `SeekBar` with `OnSeekListener`. When seeek is finished, I am calling `MediaPlayer.seek(int offset);`. This works fine when the video loads with LOW quality, but the video with HIGH quality fails to seek with the error above.

3) Target devices are almost all new Samsung android devices(SIII, SIV, TAB3, etc.) with JB 4.1+.

4) [There](http://pastebin.com/vFNUB3vq) is an video stream specification (output of WVMetaPrint)

Thank You for any suggestions and comments.

Comment: Hi, In one of my previous project, I had to play with short videos. I don't know if it can solve your problem but you should give a try to [vitamio] (http://vitamio.org/). For me, it solved fragmentation problems. Their videoView/mediaPlayer have the same api as android ones.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunatelly it seems like vitamio does not support DRM protection. Thanks for suggestion anyway!

Comment: hey can you share a url to one of these videos?

Comment: Hi, thank you for comment. As I said, this videos are DRM protected, you will not be able to play those videos without additional parameters. But I will test another non-protected video stream and then I'll share a link to you.

Comment: IIRC, I was seeing error -110 when MediaPlayer wasn't able to access the stream URL (ie: the webserver rejected the connection for that particular URL).

Comment: Ok, but video starts playing correctly, so connection should be fine. This error occurs after I seek to different position.